# How to add DialogflowCX conditions

Tags: dialogflow-cx

How do I add a conditional statement in Dialogflow CX

I have the following webhook but it is not recognized in the dialogflow intents, it returns the default intent.

```
elif intent == "MeterRegistration_ConfirmVendingOptionIntent":
                if "yes" in query.lower() or "correct" in query.lower() or "that's right" in query.lower():
                    vendingOption = parameters.get("vendingOption")
                    if vendingOption:
                        if vendingOption.lower() == "chainstore vending":
                            fulfillmentText = "Great, you've confirmed Chainstore Vending. Please provide your bank details."
                        elif vendingOption.lower() == "private vending":
                            fulfillmentText = "You've confirmed Private Vending. You don't need to provide bank details. Please contact Recharger on 010 880 8000 for more information."
                    else:
                        fulfillmentText = "You confirmed, but I couldn't determine the vending option. Could you please specify it again?"
                else:
                    fulfillmentText = "You did not confirm. Would you like to choose a vending option again?"
                print(f"Processed query for 'MeterRegistration_ConfirmVendingOptionIntent', fulfillmentText: {fulfillmentText}")
```

Happy to provide more details on the flow.

[DialogflowCX Flow of the Agent]
[image]

I am expecting the chatbot to recognize the webhook and apply the intents accordingly.